# How do I make spaces between sentences and radio buttons and text boxes? (HTML)

Tags: php, html, spacing

I have the following code and would like to separate the following items about 10 inches apart from each other. I am creating a form where a user are able to read their inputs. Here is How I would like for it to be:
Name:.......................... TEXTBOX (Without the periods)

```
<body>
<lable>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
<lable>
<p>E-mail:
</label>     
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
</p>
<lable>
Website:</label>  <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
<lable>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<lable>
Hello Gender:
           <input type="radio" name="gender"
<?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?>
value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender"
<?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?>value="male">Male
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Bad idea :**  `&nbsp`, **Good Idea :** `Use Tables`

Comment: `<lable>` should be -> `<label>` like you have on the close tag. (doesn't fix your problem, just a note)

Comment: [Tables for general layout are discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html). Use CSS methds instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use margin-left property.

use this css for your code and it should work.

```
label {
    width:180px;
    clear:left;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10px;
}

input, label {
    float:left;
    margin-left:30px
}
```

and form goes like this

```
<body>
<label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
<label>E-mail:</label>     
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
<label> Website:</label>  <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
<label>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qAhQf/213/

Answer (score 0):

```
   <label for="dummy1">title for dummy1:</label>
   <input id="dummy1" name="dummy1" value="dummy1">
   <label for="dummy2">longer title for dummy2:</label>
   <input id="dummy2" name="dummy2" value="dummy2">
   <label for="dummy3">even longer title for dummy3:</label>
   <input id="dummy3" name="dummy3" value="dummy3">
```

**css:**

```
label {
    width:250px;
    clear:left;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:50px;
}

input, label {
    float:left;
}
```

Is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use table to get as you want. Then you can give width for whole column by providing width to first cell of table.

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width=100><lable>Name:</label> </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><lable>E-mail:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><lable>Website:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>"></td>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Hello Gender:<label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
                <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: [Tables for general layout are discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html). Use CSS methds instead.

Comment: Admit. But I will keep my post here as it is another option one can use.